# How to get data-id when carousel glyphicon is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to grab an id, but it is in a slider and the only click event I get access to is the arrows, but they cannot take the unique id of the image.  I know there must be a way traverse to the div but that is a little out of my league right now.  I did try anything that I found or that came to me but have been unsuccessful so far.

The code for the slider

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide fluid col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" data-ride="carousel" style="height:95%;background-color: #000;">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active" style="border:1px solid #febe27;margin-bottom:125px;"></li>
    {% for storyItem in craft.entries.section('stories').find() %}
    {% for previewImage in storyItem.slideshowImage %}  
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" style="border:1px solid #febe27;margin-bottom:125px;"></li>
   {% endfor %}  
   {%endfor%}
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="height:87%;position:relative;">
  <div class="item active">
    {% for storyItem in craft.entries.section('stories').limit(1) %}
     {% for previewImage in storyItem.slideshowImage %}  
    <div id="{{storyItem.id}}" class="imgContentWrapper 1" data-id="{{storyItem.id}}"><a href="#"><img src="{{ previewImage.url('slideshowImage') }}" alt="" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {%endfor%}
</div>

{% for storyItem in craft.entries.section('stories').offset(1) %}
{% for previewImage in storyItem.slideshowImage %}  
  <div class="item ">
    <div id="{{storyItem.id}}" class="imgContentWrapper" data-id="{{storyItem.id}}"><a href="#"><img src="{{ previewImage.url('slideshowImage') }}" alt="" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %} 
  {%endfor%}
 </div>

 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:-25px;"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:-25px;"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

I am trying to grab the {{ storyItem.id }} in the divs (there is two the active and the regular item) on the glyphicon 'click'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trying to grab the {{ storyItem.id }} when you click what glyphicon? The chevron-left and chevron-right?

Comment: Yes, the best I have gotten is grabbing the id, but it grabs first one over and  over, I cannot seem to get the id of $(this), the id is different for each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick mate...

```
$('.glyphicon-chevron-left, .glyphicon-chevron-right').on('click', function() {
    var id = $('.carousel-inner').find('item.active').find('.imgContentWrapper').data('id');
});
```

Comment: comes back as undefined when I console.log (id)

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as a complete block of code so we can see the full picture?

Comment: sorry the one closing div got cut off, for some reason it is giving me  a hard time getting all that in one window, there is nothing missing between the two though and that is the entire top of the file other then the layout extend which is just a template thing.

Comment: Ok, so do you want the `{{ storyItem.id }}` of the `active` slide?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `a.carousel-control` are in the same `#myCarousel` div as your images. If so you can traverse to the parent and find the image you want like this:

```
$('.carousel-control').on('click', function() {
    var imageId = $(this).parent().find('#your_image_selector');
});
```

Comment: They are, but that grabs the first id for every one.

Comment: Is there any active image id or class that could be used as a hook?